# Getting total count of distinct values

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with 3 fields Brand,Model and BenchMark Score.

Notes regarding how the data will be in this table.

1.A brand can have different models.
2.Different Brands can have models will same name
3.There can be different Benchmark score of the a particular brand-model combination.

So the table data will look something like this

```
Brand ModelName Benchmark

B1    M1         1000
B1    M1         2000
B1    M2         3000
B1    M2         2000
B2    M1         3000
B2    M3         4000
```

Now what i need is to find is the number of time a particular benchmark score is reported.

Here we should count only those benchmark score which is the maximum for a model-brand combination and not all those benchmark scores.

The result should be like this

```
Score Times
3000  2
2000  1
4000  1
```

So what should be the mysql statement if i need this result..please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT MX,COUNT(1) SC FROM
(SELECT MAX(MaxScores.MaxScore) MX,ScoreCounts.ScoreCount FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(BenchMark) MaxScore,Brand,ModelName
    FROM benchmarks GROUP BY Brand,ModelName
) MaxScores
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) ScoreCount,Brand,ModelName
    FROM benchmarks GROUP BY Brand,ModelName
) ScoreCounts
USING (Brand,ModelName)
GROUP BY Brand,ModelName
) A GROUP BY MX) AA ORDER BY SC DESC,MX;
```

This query produced exactly what you are looking for and displays the result in the exact order your question has it. I tried it out with your sample data from the question. Here is what I got:

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> drop table if exists benchmarks;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE benchmarks (Brand CHAR(2),ModelName CHAR(2),BenchMark INT,key (Brand,ModelName));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO benchmarks VALUES
    -> ('B1','M1',1000),
    -> ('B1','M1',2000),
    -> ('B1','M2',3000),
    -> ('B1','M2',2000),
    -> ('B2','M1',3000),
    -> ('B2','M3',4000);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE benchmarks\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: benchmarks
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `benchmarks` (
  `Brand` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ModelName` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BenchMark` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `Brand` (`Brand`,`ModelName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM benchmarks;
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| Brand | ModelName | BenchMark |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| B1    | M1        |      1000 |
| B1    | M1        |      2000 |
| B1    | M2        |      3000 |
| B1    | M2        |      2000 |
| B2    | M1        |      3000 |
| B2    | M3        |      4000 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM
    -> (SELECT MX,COUNT(1) SC FROM
    -> (SELECT MAX(MaxScores.MaxScore) MX,ScoreCounts.ScoreCount FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT MAX(BenchMark) MaxScore,Brand,ModelName
    ->     FROM benchmarks GROUP BY Brand,ModelName
    -> ) MaxScores
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> (
    ->     SELECT COUNT(1) ScoreCount,Brand,ModelName
    ->     FROM benchmarks GROUP BY Brand,ModelName
    -> ) ScoreCounts
    -> USING (Brand,ModelName)
    -> GROUP BY Brand,ModelName
    -> ) A GROUP BY MX) AA ORDER BY SC DESC,MX;
+------+----+
| MX   | SC |
+------+----+
| 3000 |  2 |
| 2000 |  1 |
| 4000 |  1 |
+------+----+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  b.model, b.brand, bd.score, COUNT(*)
FROM    (
        SELECT  model, brand, MAX(score) AS mscore
        FROM    benchmark
        GROUP BY
                model, brand
        ) bd
JOIN    benchmark b
ON      b.model = bd.model
        AND b.brand = bd.brand
        AND b.score = bd.mscore
GROUP BY
        b.model, b.brand
```

Create an index on `(model, brand, score)` for this to work fast.

**Update:**

```
SELECT  score, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM    benchmark
GROUP BY
        score
ORDER BY
        cnt DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result i need is different. like suppose if one brand-model combination got 3000 and 2000 as score and another brand-model combination got 3000 and 1000 as score.., then the result i need is "3000 - 2 times" ..hope you got my point

Comment: my requirement is that we should consider only the max benchmark score for any brand-model combination and the result should give the total count of each of those benchmark scores..Ronaldo's answer gives me exactly what i was looking for..nyways thanks for your help and time